# rails 4 Unpermitted parameters: post_detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting following error in console

```
Unpermitted parameters: post_detail
Unpermitted parameters: post_detail
```

My post model has

```
has_many :post_details
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_details
```

and my post_detial model has

```
belongs_to :post
has_attached_file :upload
```

`post.rb` and `post_detail.rb` is my model files
`posts_controller` is controller
Here is my form

Here is my posts_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.build.post_detail
end
    private
      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title,:post_details => [:upload_file_name,:upload_file_size,:upload_file_content])
      end
```

**Edit 1**

```
<%= form_for @post,html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title,placeholder: 'title' %>
<%= f.fields_for :post_detail do |uploads| %>
<%= uploads.file_field :upload %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

My post controller

```
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.post_details.build
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      #some flash
    end
  end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,:post_details_attributes => [:id, :upload_file_name,:upload_file_size,:upload_file_content,:_destroy])
  end
```

Still `unpermitted parameters: post_details` occurs

Answer (score 0):

You should build the `post_details` in the `new` action, and then save the post with all the params (including the `post_details_attributes`) in the `create` action.

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.post_details.build
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
end
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,:post_details_attributes => [:id, :upload_file_name,:upload_file_size,:upload_file_content, :_destroy])
  end
```

Comment: I guess the :id does not have to be mass-assigned.

Comment: If you don't mass-assign the `id` I think it will create a new `post_details` each time you edit it.

Comment: @gabrielhilal It is not inserting anything to post_details table. Ill update my question what i have changed

Comment: if you are using `nested_attributes` it means you will create the `post_details` within the `post`, so the `build` method should be in the `new` action and not `create`. Also, your form should be `f.fields_for :post_details` (plural).